# AngularJS ngAnimate not working if window is not focused

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm trying to use ngAnimate via JS to manage animations on a ngRepeat, but the animate functions (enter, leave, move) are not triggered if the window (or tab) is not focused.

Here the code:

```
angular.module('Lusy').animation('.conversation-item', ['animation',         
function (animation) {
    return {
        // make note that other events (like addClass/removeClass)
        // have different function input parameters
        enter: function (element, doneFn) {
            console.log("Conversation item enter!");            
            animation.question.systemInputAdded(element);
            doneFn();
        },
        leave: function (element, doneFn) {
            console.log("Conversation item leave!");
            animation.question.userInputRemoved(element);
            doneFn();
        }
    }
}]);
```

If the browser tab is not the active one, this functions are never called.
Is there a solution for this? How can I force the animate module to be evaluated even if the window is blurred?

Comment: You have to improve question by codes, images and ... (help users to understand your question)

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I just added some code, but it doesn't add too much value. Basically the animation module seems not working if the tab is not focused.